# Gdalinfo - missing corner coordinates

Tags: gdal, noaa, gdalinfo

I came across some KAP charts which don't display correct corner coordinates from **gdalinfo**; despite them having REF fields in the header. For the NOAA file11425_3.KAP **gdalinfo** displays the coordinates:

```
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 7820.0)
Upper Right (23476.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (23476.0, 7820.0)
Center      (11738.0, 3910.0)
```

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: GDAL does not find or understand the georeferencing info. Without a test image nobody can tell you more, I fear.

Comment: @user30184 datasource is http://www.charts.noaa.gov/RNCs/RNCsIndv.shtml, especially http://www.charts.noaa.gov/RNCs/11425.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.kap` file contains GCP information. If you want gdalinfo to report the extent in real world coordinates, use gdalwarp to reproject the coordinates:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:4326 11425_3.kap 11425_3.tif

Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -82.7970104,  27.6144688) ( 82d47'49.24"W, 27d36'52.09"N)
Lower Left  ( -82.7970104,  27.0521030) ( 82d47'49.24"W, 27d 3' 7.57"N)
Upper Right ( -82.3611248,  27.6144688) ( 82d21'40.05"W, 27d36'52.09"N)
Lower Right ( -82.3611248,  27.0521030) ( 82d21'40.05"W, 27d 3' 7.57"N)
```